# PHP Upload and Resize Image copyresample issue. Image saves all BLACK

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

Image upload seems to be working, however the end result file is all black area.  No image.

The size seems correct, but the new image is just blank.

Any input greatly appreciated.  This may be something simple that I am overlooking, I just need a second set of eyes.

```
/***** IMAGE UPLOAD VARIABLES *****/
// Destination
    $main_dest = "../test_img/";
    $thumb_dest = "../test_img/thumb/";
// Main Image Width
    $new_img_width = "650";
// Thumb Image Width
    $new_img_thumb_width = "100";
// Allowed Filesize (5mb)
    $allowed_img_size = "5000000";
// Define Error Message
    $error = "";

/***** EVENT EXISTING IMAGE INFO *****/
// Get image count
    $get = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_event_imgs` WHERE `event_id` = '".$event_id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($database_link, $get);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// Main Setting
    if ($count == 0) { $main = 1; } else { $main = 0; }

/***** IMAGE INFORMATION *****/
// Get image temporary name
    $img_tmp = $_FILES['event_image']['tmp_name'];
// Get image name (original)
    $img_name = basename($_FILES['event_image']['name']);
// Get image extension
    $img_ext = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Get image size
    $img_size = $_FILES['event_image']['size'];
// Final image destination
    $final_main_dest = $main_dest.$img_name;

/***** IMAGE VALIDATION *****/
// Validate Image Type (jpg, jpeg, gif, png)
    if (($img_ext !== "jpg") && ($img_ext !== "jpeg") && ($img_ext !== "gif") && ($img_ext !== "png")) {
        $upload_error = 1;
        $error .= "filetype";
    }
// Validate Image Size  (5mb Allowed)
    if ($img_size > $allowed_img_size) {
        $upload_error = 1;
        $error .= "filesize";
    }

/**** BEGIN UPLOAD *****/
// Set src image (by ext)
    if (($img_ext == "jpg" ) || ($img_ext == "jpeg")) {
        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_tmp);
    } elseif ($img_ext == "png") {
        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($img_tmp);
    } elseif ($img_ext == "gif") {
        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($img_tmp);
    }
// Get src image height and width
    $src_img_width = imagesx($src_img);
    $src_img_height = imagesy($src_img);
// Set "desired" height
    $new_img_height = floor($src_img_height * ($new_img_width / $src_img_width));
// Create Virtual Images
    $virtual_main_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_img_width, $new_img_height);
// Resize source image
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_main_image, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_img_width, $new_img_height, $src_img_width, $src_img_height);
// Save final images
    imagejpeg($virtual_main_img, $final_main_dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being simple:

$virtual_main_img was defined variable.

I inadvertently used "$virtual_main_image".

Works.